# Connecting to two different hosts that uses two different database systems node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb

I would like to connect to two different servers at the same time with Node.js

Let's say I would like to get some text from a server with MySQL database and get some other text from another server with MongoDB and compare these texts.

How would I do that ?

Comment: Just make two connection,  read necessary data from databases and then compare these data in the your application (NodeJS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const url = "mongodb://<YOUR_CONNECTION_STRING>";
var config = {
    mysql_pool : mysql.createPool({
        host     : '<HOST>',
        user     : '<USER>',
        password : '<PASS>',
       database : '<DB>'
    }); 
};

var mySqlPromise =  new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
   config.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
    connection.query('{YOUR QUERY}' ,[{FIELDS}], function (err, rows) {
     if(err){
      reject(err);
     }else{
      resolve(rows);  
     } 
     connection.release();
    });
  });
});

var mongoPromise = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
   MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
      if (err) throw err;
      var dbo = db.db("mydb");
      dbo.collection("<YOURCOllECTION>").findOne({<Query>}, function(err, result) {
       if (err) reject(err);
       resolve(result);
       db.close();
    });
  });
});

Promise.all([mySqlPromise, mongoPromise],function(result){
   //here result[0] is mysql result and result[1] is mongo result do your computation
}).catch(function(err){
  //in case of error code here
});
```

After connecting both db in nodejs. You can just query individual database with promise and afterwards using promise.all you can compare strings once both the results are fetched. Sample code is shown above.

Comment: Your answer is not relevant to the question. Question is to connect with two server/database not single one.

Comment: @SachinShah please read carefully i have mentioned both database connection example links.

Comment: Yes that is correct but need example to access both on one code. This is what any  one can search from google.

Comment: If possible then add some real example so he/she can get clear idea on issue.

Comment: @SachinShah i have updated sample code as well. :)

Comment: Ok, I will try this. Thanks.